Hadoop INIT_FAILD: Data is not Replicated on DataNode
I am using Hadoop 3.2.4 as standalone service on Windows 11 23H2 OS, I am trying to ingest the data from Apache Nifi into the hadoop hdfs two-node cluster.

NameNode (Also behaving as Datanode1) - Apche Nifi is also Running
on the same node.
DataNode2 (Running on Another System in the same
network)

When I had ingested the data using puthdfs processor in Apache Nifi, it had replicate the data on Datanode1 but I am not seeing the replicated block on the other Datanode2 i.e. running on another system in the same network. Below is the error which I am seeing on Datanode Web UI interface.

In my organization, the network administrator has blocked ping (ICMP) requests, can this be the issue that causing the issue of RPC between namenode and datanode?
Below are the configuration files:
NameNode hadfs-site.xml
<configuration>
    <!-- Replication factor for HDFS -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
        <value>supergroup</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <!-- NameNode directory to store metadata -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/hadoopsetup/hadoop-3.2.4/data/dfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/hadoopsetup/hadoop-3.2.4/data/dfs/secondary</value>
    </property>

    <!-- DataNode directory to store HDFS blocks -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/hadoopsetup/hadoop-3.2.4/data/dfs/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Allow NameNode to also act as a DataNode -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/hadoopsetup/hadoop-3.2.4/data/dfs/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Address and port for the NameNode -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
        <value>10.5.1.202:9000</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Address and port for Secondary NameNode -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
        <value>10.5.1.202:50090</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

DataNode hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
        <value>supergroup</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Replication factor for HDFS -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
  
    <!-- DataNode directory to store HDFS blocks -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/hadoopsetup/hadoop-3.2.4/data/dfs/datanode</value>
    </property>  
</configuration>

All datanodes are appearing on Hadoop http:<ip address>:8088/cluster.  Why am I unable to replicate data among Hadoop cluster while it is being copied on datanode1 running on the same namenode?

You should share your datanode + namenode logs
